# Validate date column for PySpark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, date, validation, pyspark, typeerror

I want to validate a date column for a PySpark dataframe. I know how to do it for pandas, but can't make it work for PySpark.

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
data = [['Alex',10, '2001-01-12'],['Bob',12, '2005-10-21'],['Clarke',13, '2003-12-41']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Sale_qty', 'DOB'])
sparkDF =spark.createDataFrame(df) 


def validate(date_text):
    try:
        if date_text != datetime.strptime(date_text, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime('%Y-%m-%d'):
            raise ValueError
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

df = df['DOB'].apply(lambda x: validate(x))     

print(df)
```

It works for pandas dataframe. But I can't make it work for PySpark. Getting the following error:

```py
sparkDF = sparkDF['DOB'].apply(lambda x: validate(x))
```

> ```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-83-5f5f1db1c7b3> in <module>
> ----> 1 sparkDF = sparkDF['DOB'].apply(lambda x: validate(x))
>
> TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following column expression:

```py
F.to_date('DOB', 'yyyy-M-d').isNotNull()
```

Full test:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [['Alex', 10, '2001-01-12'], ['Bob', 12, '2005'], ['Clarke', 13, '2003-12-41']]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['Name', 'Sale_qty', 'DOB'])

validation = F.to_date('DOB', 'yyyy-M-d').isNotNull()

df.withColumn('validation', validation).show()
# +------+--------+----------+----------+
# |  Name|Sale_qty|       DOB|validation|
# +------+--------+----------+----------+
# |  Alex|      10|2001-01-12|      true|
# |   Bob|      12|      2005|     false|
# |Clarke|      13|2003-12-41|     false|
# +------+--------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. If I also have some date values like this '20010112' , what argument should I use instead of 'yyyy-M-d'

Comment: 'yyyyMMdd' will work with '20010112'.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `to_date()` with the required source date format. It returns `null` where the format is incorrect, which can be used for validation.

see below example.

```py
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('01-12-2001',), ('2001-01-12',)]).toDF(['dob']). \
    withColumn('correct_date_format', func.to_date('dob', 'yyyy-MM-dd').isNotNull()). \
    show()

# +----------+-------------------+
# |       dob|correct_date_format|
# +----------+-------------------+
# |01-12-2001|              false|
# |2001-01-12|               true|
# +----------+-------------------+
```